# Can I share one SPN between two service accounts?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, kerberos, ssrs, spn

I am running IIS and SQL Reporting Server on the same server. IIS runs as `d\acct1` and SSRS is running as `d\acct2`.

Initially, I registered an SPN `HTTP/server.d.com` for both `d\acct1` and `d\acct2` and configured both for unconstrained kerberos delegation in Active Directory.

This configuration broke kerberos because there were duplicate SPNs for `HTTP/server.d.com`.

If I delete the SPN for SSRS, IIS works. If I delete the SPN for IIS, SSRS works.

Is there a way to share an SPN between two different service accounts that run on the same server such that they do not create a duplicate SPN?

Or, must I create two A records in active directory for `iis.server.d.com` and `reports.server.d.com` and use host headers to keep the two aliases straight inside each respective service?

Comment: Why do you think that you have to use host headers? They are not a must.

Comment: I decided to use multiple IP addresses rather than host headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research into how Kerberos delegation works shows that no, you cannot share SPNs between service accounts on the same box.

I solved the problem by provisioning a second IP address for my server and mapping IIS to one IP address and SSRS to the other.

I then created two new A records in DNS (don't use C records, they are unreliable with Kerberos delegation) to point to the services. `iis.server.d.com` points to the IIS IP address and `ssrs.server.d.com` points to the SSRS IP.

Lastly, I deleted all the SPNs for both `d\acct1` and `d\acct2` and reassigned the SPNs as `HTTP/iis.server.d.com` and `HTTP/ssrs.server.d.com` respectively.

Additionally, I find that editing SPNs using [ADSIEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(WS.10).aspx) *far* easier than using the `setspn` command line.

Comment: You actually should be using SetSPN from W2K8 or Vista - MS added the -S and -F parms to add an SPN, but only if it doesn't exist. Basically a "don't shoot myself in the foot" check before adding the SPN.

Comment: That is great info. I'll have to look into that.